# Get a list of all applications that SikuliX currently sees

Tags: winforms, sikuli

I have an application that doesn't appear to be responding to SikuliX's (v 1.1.2) .focus(). It is one of three custom WinForms applications I have running. I found [this link](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/183901) pertaining to my exact situation, but the suggestions did not help.

I have been able to get the code to work for Chrome, SQL Server, and other random applications I have running at the time. The problem seems to come in when I have more than one type of application running. If my applications are named "Version Launcher", "Device 1", and "Alternative", I am able to switch to "Version Launcher", but "Device 1" and "Alternative" aren't found.

```
class myDevice:

    def startApp(self):
        #my_app = App("Chrome") # works
        #my_app = App("Visual Studio") # works
        #my_app = App("Version Selector") # works
        #my_app = App("Device 1") # does NOT work
        my_app = App("Alternative") # does NOT work

        my_app.focus(); wait(1)

my_device = myDevice()
my_device.startApp()
```

In order to rule out a bad name (perhaps, on some level, the application is not really named "Device 1"), I'd like to build a list of every application that Sikulix can detect at runtime. Has anyone ever tried such a thing? I've searched all over the documentation and cannot find any features that allows for this sort of querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raimund Hocke, the maintainer of the SikuliX project, answered my question over on launchpad.
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/664004

In short, SikuliX uses the 'tasklist' command in Windows to grab the list of available applications.